# Redirect Bots crawling URLs with parameters to category page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i need to redirect all bots crawling for URLs like this:

> example.com/en/percussion/drums/?p=1&f=56%7C286%7C55%7C319%7C30%7C36%7C16%7C573%7C311%7C224%7C35%7C322%7C364

They should be redirected to main category:

> example.com/en/percussion/drums/

with a 301 redirect in htaccess.
But this rule should be only for bots like googlebot or others.

Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{query_STRING} ^p=1&f=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule (.*) what to write here? [L,R=301]
```

I don't know how to create a correct RewriteRule, which redirects to the requested URL, but without Query_Strings (example.com/en/percussion/drums/).

Any idea?

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `?` at the end to remove the query string, so try:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{query_STRING} ^p=1&f=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've tried this, but result is:
_example.com/en/_
But i need a result like: 
_example.com/en/percussion/drums/_

I've also tried this:
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{query_STRING} ^p=1&f=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]`

Query string is gone, but redirect is leading to Main Page, URL:
_example.com/en/_

Comment: @BassDrum something else is redirecting you